# Spring Boot SSL does not redirect HTTP to HTTPS for everyone

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have setup HTTPS for my website with a SSL cert, everything seems to work just fine, if i type in www.realmlands.com it redirects me to https:// and if i remove the "s" on https:// and hit enter it will also redirect to https:// but the issue lies with other people, when they go to www.realmlands.com it says unsecure and it wont let them login as its not https:// but it should be redirecting them automatically.

I have tried this configuration which seems to work most of the time.

```
    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(
                TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("https");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(true);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        return connector;
    }
```

It should be redirecting everyone to https:// but some people see unsecure and are allowed to use http://

Comment: I would say, the better way to allow `http`, `https`, `www domain`, naked domain is using nginx proxy.

Comment: i do not want to use http as its not secure, using http is not an option, only https, the issue is it works for like 90% of people, the 10% have to manually add the "s" in https, the 90% it will auto direct to https